# Powershell set starting position for read data

Tags: regex, excel, powershell, foreach

Folks, I am new to Poweshell scripting and i have been googling a lot to get snippets of code and understanding what it does and customizing it to my need. I am in need of help for a small project I am working on. I have an EXCEL spread sheet with just one worksheet in it. I downloaded the excel from a 3rd party URL and within the excel worksheet i have data. There are a few cells in the top part of the excel that I would like to ignore and start from the row which actually has a table with a header. With what I have I hard coded the value of the starting position and and then I am writing the values into a PIPE delimited text file  by doing a line by line read using a for loop. Now I would like to get that header field dynamically based on a string in the columns of that specific row and then start to read from that position till the end of file.

The source data looks something like this.

source data:

[image]

I have the code like this. As you can see I have the columns hard coded and then writing the data into a text file I create at the top. I want to make the starting position a dynamic based on header string and it may be present in any position (in this case it happened to be 11).

```
#Download the Medicare Fee Scheule for the state website for the respective year

$url "https://med.noridianmedicare.com/documents/10525/23843395/California%2C%20Area+05%2C%202020+Medicare+Part+B+Fee+Schedule+Excel+File"
$path = "\\srqsctfs01\sftp\BA\MedicareFeeSchedule"
$archivepath = "\\srqsctfs01\sftp\BA\MedicareFeeSchedule\Archive" # Setting the Archive File path variable to moving the excel file to archive location
$file = "MedicareFeeSchedule2020_SFCounty" # Set a file name variable
$filename = $file + ".xlsx"
$outputfilepath = $path + "\" + $filename #Declare the Output filepath variable
$archivefilepath = $archivepath + "\" + $filename   #"# dummy comment to fix syntax highlighting in SO
$start_time = Get-Date
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $outputfilepath)
#OR
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $outputfilepath)
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
#Declare the file path and sheet name
$sheetName = "California, Area 05"

# CREATE AN EMPTY TEXT FILE ONLY IF IT DOES NOT ALREADY EXIST

$FileName = "MedicareFeeSchedule2020_SFCounty" + "_" + (Get-Date).tostring("MM-dd-yyyy")
$TextFilePath = $path + "\" + $FileName + ".txt"    #"# dummy comment to fix syntax highlighting in SO
if (!(Test-Path $TextFilePath))
{
New-Item -itemType File -Path $path -Name ($FileName + ".txt")
}
else
{
    Remove-Item $TextFilePath
}
#Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($outputfilepath)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false
#Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
#Declare the starting positions
$rowNote,$colNote = 11,1
$rowProcedureCode,$colProcedureCode = 11,2
$rowModifier,$colModifier = 11,3
$rowParAmount,$colParAmount = 11,4
$rowNonParAmount,$colNonParAmount = 11,5
$rowLimitingChargeAmount,$colLimitingChargeAmount = 11,6
#loop to get values and store it
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{
    $Note = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowNote+$i,$colNote).text
    $ProcedureCode = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowProcedureCode+$i,$colProcedureCode).text
    $Modifier = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowModifier+$i,$colModifier).text
    $ParAmount = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowParAmount+$i,$colParAmount).text
    $NonParAmount = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowNonParAmount+$i,$colNonParAmount).text
    $LimitingChargeAmount = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowLimitingChargeAmount+$i,$colLimitingChargeAmount).text
    $string = ($Note + "|"  + $ProcedureCode + "|" + $Modifier + "|" + $ParAmount + "|" + $NonParAmount + "|" + $LimitingChargeAmount)
    $string | Out-File -FilePath $TextFilePath -Append
}

#close excel file

$objExcel.quit()
```

Any help to make this happen is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Prabhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify this by capturing the values in objects having the wanted properties and then write this out as pipe delimited csv file like this:

```
# Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($outputfilepath)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false
# Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
# determine the row number where the table data starts
$rowFirst = 11
$colFirst = 1

# loop to get values and store it
$result = for ($i = $rowFirst; $i -le $rowMax; $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Note                 = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst).text                       # or perhaps use .Value2 instead of .Text
        ProcedureCode        = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 1).text
        Modifier             = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 2).text
        ParAmount            = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 3).text
        NonParAmount         = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 4).text
        LimitingChargeAmount = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 5).text

    }
}

# close excel file
$objExcel.Quit()

# IMPORTANT: remove the COM objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# show on screen
$result | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|'

# output to pipe delimited CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\TheTable.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

A Csv file of course has a header and also quotes around the values.
If you do insist on outputting a pipe delimited text file with no header and no quotes, you can do that same as above, but for the output use:

```
$result | ForEach-Object { $_.PsObject.Properties.Value -join '|' }
```

To file then would be:

```
$result | ForEach-Object { $_.PsObject.Properties.Value -join '|' } | Out-File -FilePath $TextFilePath
```

Comment: Hi Theo, Thank you very much for a better elegant solution. If I need the header row in the PIPE delimited file, how would I alter your last statement? I am including the code that I used and with yours merged so anyone that needs it can use it for their project(s).

Comment: I think I can tweak the part where I set the $k value to just the startingposition variable and that would address it.. Thanks Theo!! Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "https://med.noridianmedicare.com/documents/10525/23843395/California%2C%20Area+05%2C%202020+Medicare+Part+B+Fee+Schedule+Excel+File"
$path = "\\srqsctfs01\sftp\BA\MedicareFeeSchedule"
$archivepath = "\\srqsctfs01\sftp\BA\MedicareFeeSchedule\Archive" # Setting the Archive File path variable to moving the excel file to archive location
$file = "MedicareFeeSchedule2020_SFCounty" # Set a file name variable
$filename = $file + ".xlsx"
$outputfilepath = $path + "\" + $filename  #Declare the Output filepath variable
$archivefilepath = $archivepath + "\" + $filename
$start_time = Get-Date
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $outputfilepath)
#OR
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $outputfilepath)
Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"

# CREATE AN EMPTY TEXT FILE ONLY IF IT DOES NOT ALREADY EXIST
$FileName = "MedicareFeeSchedule2020_SFCounty" + "_" + (Get-Date).tostring("MM-dd-yyyy")
$TextFilePath = $path + "\" + $FileName + ".txt"
if (!(Test-Path $TextFilePath))
{
New-Item -itemType File -Path $path -Name ($FileName + ".txt")
}
else
{
    Remove-Item $TextFilePath
}

# Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($outputfilepath)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false

# Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
$colMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Columns).count

# Loop through each row

for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax; $i++)

{

    $row_str = ""
    for ($j=1; $j -le $colMax; $j++)
    {
        $row_str = $row_str + $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).text + "|"
        if ($row_str -like 'Note|Procedure Code|Modifier|Par Amount|Non-Par Amount|Limiting Charge Amount|')
        {
            $startposition = $i
        }
        break # BREAK OUT OF INNER FOR LOOP
    }
        $k = $startposition + 1
    break # BREAK OUT OF OUTER FOR LOOP

}
# determine the row number where the table data starts
$rowFirst = $k
$colFirst = 1

# loop to get values and store it
$result = for ($i = $rowFirst; $i -le $rowMax; $i++) {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Note                 = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst).text                       # or perhaps use .Value2 instead of .Text
        ProcedureCode        = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 1).text
        Modifier             = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 2).text
        ParAmount            = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 3).text
        NonParAmount         = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 4).text
        LimitingChargeAmount = $sheet.Cells.Item($i, $colFirst + 5).text

    }
}

# close excel file
$objExcel.Quit()

# IMPORTANT: remove the COM objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# writing output to a text file
$result | ForEach-Object { $_.PsObject.Properties.Value -join '|' } | Out-File -FilePath $TextFilePath
```